# Nullpointer @ managedQuery

Tags: java, android

When I run my code, I get an exception @ managedQuery. 
Whats wrong?
I don't see it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

public class FileManager extends Activity
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

public List<String> getAudioFiles()
{
    List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Some audio may be explicitly marked as not being music
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
    };

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            songs.add(cursor.getString(0) + "||" + cursor.getString(1) + "||" +   cursor.getString(2) + "||" +   cursor.getString(3) + "||" +  cursor.getString(4) + "||" +  cursor.getString(5));
    }

    return songs;
}
```

}

This is the exception

```
   09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.testActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:90)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1556)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at com.test.FileManager.getAudioFiles(FileManager.java:35)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at com.test.testActivity.onCreate(testActivity.java:21)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-27 17:04:20.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4079):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post your exception as well. Also, according to the Android SDK API managedQuery is deprecated (you should be using CursorLoader instead).

Comment: If you use the same e-mail on your new account as you did in your old account, I can merge your accounts and give you back ownership of this question. Please flag your question once you've done so, select 'other' and ask for a merge.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be helpful but I note that your projection is an array with a length of five and your string building method expects a sixth column (cursor.getString(5)). Of course, that wouldn't cause a NullPointerException at managedQuery, are you sure that's where the exception is occuring? Because that bit looks okay from here (apart from the fact that you define selection criteria but don't use it).